# Database-driven WebSite , Programatically render an html table with userControls

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, user-controls, dynamic-data

excuse my English as it's by far not my main one (:

I have a question which I would like to be advised on
I'll try to be as specific as I can .

Allthogh it looks as if it's a long story 
it is only a practical question to help me deside:

which tools to use 
trying to achieve a comprehensive all in one solution,
to be included in most/ majority of my future projects:

since my applications (my first "client"s demands)
(...as i am still learning to develop via C# Dot.Net)

are data-driven + repeating itself almost with every task I need to fulfill.

i was thinking of a set : best practice tools ,to use... with a few main templates-like solutions , so :

**form this List , what would be best?** (easiest/simple to implement that will match html table)

having few options to select from (to interact with database)

`ado.net` Vs `LINQ To SQL`<<--- EOL/obsolete ?

`datareader` vs `DataAdapter`

`List<Dictionary<string,Object>` vs `DataTable Dataset DataColumnCollection`

..etc

Which set of Tools from listed ones(above or if i didn't mention any you could recommend) would you use ??

so with chosen methods ,i could do something like :

call `StoredProcedureName` :paramaters - take from `DDL ID` , `DDL NAME`

`for/each` `row` of `DataBasetable` ,

draw html Table that fits the dataType retrived from DB

`<input type=text>` for `dates` / `nvarchar`

`<input type=checkBox>` if its bit

apply vallidation if its money type:
Append an event attribute `onkeyPress="ValidationfucName(this)"`

Comment: @Aristos sorry , i did try to narow it down i allso have a code ready to use i didnt post it i was woried it will be too long to read . so i put a "**bold**"er question title above the list of tools availble in `Asp.net 4.0` , to simplefy my question.. have a second look please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try asp:GridView. You can widely configure it to your needs.

Comment: i know it, though at first i thought not to use the gridview although if i will use it and i will configure it through the code behind via item template it would be perfect as i later want to achive the option to post back data with ajax/javascript/jquery for CRUD so i will have both the automtic process of generating rows plus post backs-database interaction/queries without using the builtin func' of GV, thats it! then i can have a smooth automatic database interaction without page refresh and without .aspx.side working on tables so the gridview control will render htmltblRows programatically

Comment: You can "avoid" AJAX by using UpdatePanel and ScriptManager. Mark as answer?

Comment: did . cause actually did use it (;

Answer (score 1):

after creating linq to sql class 
use your code as follow

```
objectclassname object = new objectclassname()
```

for grideview you use following linq query

```
objectclassname objectname = new objectclassname();
var txtvalue = objectname.tablename.single(p=> p.stratwith("value you want to find"));
grideviewidname.datasource = txtvalue.tolist();
grideviewname.databind();
```

Comment: @usrer1.... thanks looks good and simple i am going to give it a try asap, + i will post what i already tried b4 you've posted your Answer , thanks